# Is possible to use a groovy package on indigo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm needing to use obj_rec_gui package on indigo and the package isn't available on indigo, but it is on groovy. How can I use it on indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204017/is-possible-to-use-a-groovy-package-on-indigo?/) by [Guil](https://answers.ros.org/users/21750/guil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try downloading the source code for the groovy version of the package and building it on Indigo.

If you run into issues, you may need to update the package if any of the APIs that it uses have changed. The [Hydro migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration) and the [Indigo migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration) give an overview of which packages have changed and how to update code that uses them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-03-02**:
and if you successfully migrated the package don't forget to create a pull request.